# SSIS export to excel

Tags: export-to-excel, ssis

Using SSMS I created an export a query to Excel and saved it as a DTSX package. Imported this DTSX package into a BIDS project to make it run hourly and export a excel file with timestamp appended to it, dynamic name using expressions. When I run from BIDS, package executes successfully and creates the excel file without a problem. I have enabled DelayedValidation flag.
I can double click on the DTSX file, run the package and it creates the excel file without a problem. When I configure as a SQL Job, it fails with the below error

Any guidance is much appreciated

```
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.2500.0 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    
    Started:  2:53:03 PM  
    Error: 2012-09-21 14:53:05.54     
    Code: 0xC0202009     
    Source: Export MyExportQuery to Excel Destination - Query [73]     
    Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E37.  End Error  
    Error: 2012-09-21 14:53:05.54     
    Code: 0xC02020E8     
    Source: Export MyExportQuery to Excel Destination - Query [73]     
    Description: Opening a rowset for "Query" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.  End Error  
    Error: 2012-09-21 14:53:05.54     
    Code: 0xC004701A     
    Source: Export MyExportQuery to Excel SSIS.Pipeline     
    Description: component "Destination - Query" (73) failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC02020E8.  End Error  
    DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  
    Started:  2:53:03 PM  
    Finished: 2:53:05 PM  
    Elapsed:  2.282 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.
```

EDIT:
SSIS is configured to run in 32 bit mode

Comment: So why you voted me down if I gave you the right answer? @G33kKahuna

Comment: I don'think question is answered ... i am guessing the mods just keep closing unanswered questions

Answer (score 3):

Most of the problems arise due to these situations:

- Data source connection or File access issue (when the user running the sql agent doesn't have the right permissions to the db or to the destination file).
- Package protection level (pwd are sensitive data, and sometimes are not copied depending on the protection level).
- 64bit issue (this a common one on XL exports. Since there's no Jet Driver for 64bit systems, when running on a 64bit OS you need to either use the 32bit DTEXEC in your sql job or set the "Use 32bit runtime" option, it's on the "Execution options" tab when you're creating a SSIS job step, check the image on link below for seeing it).

[32Bit runtime option image](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-WHsiqaOI8gA/T8_GuvdMMZI/AAAAAAAAAPE/SoqxcClaSvI/s1600/ssis.jpg)

For information on this topic, have a look at this article, it has detailed information on situations when ssis packages run on BIDS but not on SQL jobs..

[How do I troubleshoot SSIS packages failed execution in a SQL Agent job?](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/e13c137c-1535-4475-8c2f-c7e6e7d125fc)

Hope this helps you..

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

When you configure a SQL Server Agent job with a job step type of SQL Server Integration Services Package, the job invokes the **dtexec** utility. However, the version of the dtexec utility that the job invokes depends on what versions of SQL Server and SQL Server Agent have been installed and are running on the 64-bit computer. [[MSDN]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms141766(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

To run a package in *32-bit* mode from a 64-bit version of SQL Server Agent, select **Use 32 bit runtime** on the Execution options tab of the New Job Step dialog box.

[image]